# Strange behaviour with Zend_Form_Element_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-form-element

I'm having strange behaviours with my Zend Form. The fields to be filled with a "select" button remain empty (NULL) in the database, and the value of one them is put in another field.
Here's my code:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->setName('projet');
    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('codeProjet');  //works great
    $id->setLabel('Code du Projet');
    $nomproj = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nomProjet');  //is filled with the codeEntreprise value
    $nomproj->setLabel('Nom du Projet')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
    $deb = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('dateDebut');   //works great
    $deb->setLabel('Date du début')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
    $fin = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('dateFin');   //works great
    $fin->setLabel('Date de fin')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
    $montant = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('montantPrevu');  //works great
    $montant->setLabel('Montant prévu')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
    $chef = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('matriculeChef');  //remains empty
    $options=array('select'=>'[select]');
    $chef->setLabel('Chef de Projet')
    ->setRequired(true);

    $boss = new Application_Model_DbTable_Developpeur();
    foreach($boss->fetchAll() as $p)
        $options[$p['matricule']]=$p['prenom'].' '.$p['nom'];
    var_dump($options);
    $chef->addMultioptions($options);
    $chef->setValue($selected);

    $boite = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('codeEntreprise');   //remains empty
    $option=array('select'=>'[select]');
    $boite->setLabel('Nom de l\'entreprise');
    $entr = new Application_Model_DbTable_Entreprise();
    foreach($entr->fetchAll() as $p)
        $option[$p['codeEntreprise']]=$p['nom'];
    var_dump($option);
    $boite->addMultioptions($option);

    $envoyer = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('envoyer');
    $envoyer->setAttrib('id', 'boutonenvoyer');

    $this->addElements(array($id, $nomproj,$deb,$fin,$montant,$chef,$boite, $envoyer));
}
```

Do you have any idea why one field is filled with a wrong value, and why some remain empty in the database?
Thanks.

Comment: Check your variable names, you are reusing variables in the same scope. `$p` and `$options` are being used for multiple elements in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

on the following line :

```
$chef->setValue($selected);
```

where is $selected coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$form->populate($dataFromDb or $_POSTdata)` to fill the values IMO.